# Google Cloud - Passing user info from IAP to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I have an internal Cloud Run service which is protected by Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP). Is it possible to access the user info (e.g. email who is using the service) from IAP inside the application? (e.g. to log user actions)

Maybe the info is already in some environmental variable that I can access inside the application?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it help? https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto